# bringSubViewToFront not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I have an array of views that basically define colours squares on a 5x5 grid.  Each view is responsible for its own touch events and, upon touch, performs an animation.

This all works great but sometimes the animation will be clipped by the view's neighbours.  I have attempted to fix this with the following code but clipping still sometimes occurs; it seems to happen at random.  Is there anything I am missing?

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [recognizer.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view setNeedsDisplay];

    //do animation to the view here
}
```

Comment: from where did you get that recognizer object and how did you add that recognizer means direct to that view?

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you'd need `setNeedsDisplay` in this situation, as bringing the subview to front will probably do this automatically.

Comment: recognizer comes from the handleTap event that I subscribe to.. Ill update code

Comment: @mrueg I didn't originally have this, after some searching I added it hoping it would help, it evidently did not, I should remove from code. Thanks

Comment: set clipsToBounds to NO ?, what is the animation doing ? is it actually happening within the frame of the subview ?

Comment: @PizzaiolaGorgonzola The `superview` contains a grid of `view`s.  When a `view` is tapped it spins 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as,

```
[self.View bringSubviewToFront:recognizer.view];
[recognizer.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Thanks but it has not fixed it :'/